# Are questions about classes or API relevant?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering, would a question that asks about certain classes or parts of a language/API be relevant, as opposed to a question about code containing those classes?

For instance, if I were to ask what the differences are between two similar data types (like, say, `int` and `uint`), would that be relevant? Or would it be marked as off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is completely on-topic for SO, assuming that the question contents itself aren't vague or a polling type question:

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Practical, answerable problems that are *unique to the programming profession*

I would say that API questions generally only relate to the 'programming profession', and that they fall under that category.

Now, the question might already exist, or be closed for another reason, but that doesn't make it (in a general sense) 'off topic'.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was probably on-topic but figured I'd check to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

That is a valid programming question, and it is perfectly on topic.

However, most questions like int vs uint are [likely already there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095805/1069068), so I'd recommend you spend a bit of time searching before posting.

Comment: Thanks. int vs uint was just an example of course, I would only ask such a question if I can't find anything similar on SO, or indeed anywhere online.